# Simplify constructing a subclass from its parent in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

So I have a base class:

```
case class CSVRecord (
  val timestamp : String,
  val transactionId : String,
  val action : String,
  val fromMSISDN :String,
  val toMSISDN :String,
  val fromICCID :String,
  val toICCID :String,
  val finalState :String,
  val reason : String,
  val source : String
)
```

And it has a subclass of itself that I occasionally need to initialize with an instance of its parent. Is there a simpler way to do this? Right now I have to repeat every field and assign it again. Is there an easier/cleaner way to do this in Scala?

```
class Record (
  val id : Long,
  val batch_id : Long,

  timestamp : String,
  transactionId : String,
  action : String,
  fromMSISDN :String,
  toMSISDN :String,
  fromICCID :String,
  toICCID :String,
  finalState :String,
  reason : String,
  source : String

) extends     CSVRecord(timestamp,transactionId,action,fromMSISDN,toMSISDN,fromICCID,toICCID,finalState,reason,source) with KeyedEntity[Long] {
  def this() = this(0,0,"","","","","","","","","","")
  def this(id : Long, batch_id : Long, r : CSVRecord) = this(id,batch_id,r.timestamp,
    r.transactionId,r.action,r.fromMSISDN,r.toMSISDN,r.fromICCID,r.toICCID,r.finalState,r.reason,r.source)

  lazy val provisionings : OneToMany[Provisioning] = MWS.recordToProvisioning.left(this)
  lazy val batch : ManyToOne[Batch] = MWS.batchToRecord.right(this)
}
```

Comment: `Record` extending `CSVRecord`? Isn't it the reverse?

Comment: AFAIK you can't extend a case class

Comment: You can but a `case class` extending another `case class` (not the case of this post) is not recommended since there might lead to some strange issue with equality.

Answer (score 1):

Why not gathering some related fields into Value Objects (`case class`)? This would greatly reduce the writing of your subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid specifying all constructor arguments. One "workaround" if it suits your needs would be to use `def` with implementation instead of `val`:

```
trait A {
  def a: Int = 1
  def b: String = "text"
}

class B extends A
```

This works only if you have mostly getters, not setters.

Combining fields together as @Mik378 suggested is a good solution too:

```
trait BaseType

case class SharedArgs(a: Int, b: String)

case class A(args: SharedArgs) extends BaseType

case class B(args: SharedArgs, anotherArg: Int) extends BaseType
```

Not only it reduces code duplication it also makes it easier to read the code - it's easy to get lost with so many args.